# copy all control values from one page to another c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Page in Asp.net. In this Page I have two button which toggles between 2 screens, viz: 1. Add screen and 2. Update screen.

When update screen is loaded all the controls are filled with some values, while in Add screen all the control values are cleared.

Is there a way in which I could copy all the control values of update screen and fill the add screen controls with these copied values?????